# How to set an Array in a nested objects React hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, use-state

So i'm trying do set my formData with my inputFields.
I always use input with value and name, but here it's me who tell what value is it.

In my child component i have a form with an option who contain a list of name.
When a user click on a name and then on a "+" button, i increment "inputFields"

```
const handleAddFields = () => {
    setInputFields([
      //existing input
      ...inputFields,
      {
        //+ new value
        fullName: crtContact?.fullName,
        jobTitle: crtContact?.jobTitle,
        businessPhone: crtContact?.businessPhone,
        mail: crtContact?.mail,
      },
    ]);
  };
```

then, my inputFields contain an array with multiple objects,  for example :

```
[ 0: { fullName: "test1",
            jobTitle: "test1",
            businessPhone: "test1",
            mail: "test1" }
1 :  fullName: "test2",
            jobTitle: "test2",
            businessPhone: "test2",
            mail: "test2"} ]
```

But now, i need to set this inputFields into another state (the one that i send to my db)
here it's my parents comp :

```
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([]);

const initialFormData = {
    general: {
      country: "",
      zip: "", 
    },
    contact: [
      {
        fullName: "",
        jobTitle: "",
        businessPhone: "",
        mail: "",
      },
    ],
 
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);


const handleOnChange = (e, index) => {
 
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      general: {
        ...formData.general,
        [name]: value,
      },
      contact: {
       //HERE MY INPUTFIELDS 
      },
     
    });
  };
```

I have try so many things but i can't resolve this...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use pass callback function to `setFormData` like:

```
setFormData((formData) => ({
   ...formData,
   general: {
      ...formData.general,
      [name]: value,
   },
   contact: {
      //HERE MY INPUTFIELDS 
   },
}));
```

Comment: Well, "general" is working fine but it's really "contact" the problem.

Comment: Can you provide your source code in codesandbox or other same online editor?